# display file properties in nstableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsfilemanager

I want to display files' data in a tableview . Files are stored in a directory. I want to display in the tableview : the icon , name , size and the date of the files. Thanks to NSFileManger , I found how to display directory's content ,but I can't display the properties as I want. 
Do you have any suggestion of how does it work , idea , tutorial?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the content of the directory, call `NSFileManger`'s `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` method on the path of each file. The method returns an `NSDictionary` of file attributes of each particular file. Grab the attributes that you want using their keys - `NSFileType`, `NSFileSize`, `NSFileModificationDate`, and so on; all keys are listed in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This will give you everything except the icon, for which you need to use [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `iconForFile:` method.